# how can find the latest subdir

Tags: bash

I have the following structure

```
/storage/archive/mp3/A/1dir
/storage/archive/mp3/A/2dir
/storage/archive/mp3/A/3dir/a3dir
/storage/archive/mp3/A/4dir/a4dir/a44dir
```

I always want to output the last subdir with the path

```
#! /bin/sh
for list in $listdir/*
do
    dirname="${list#*/}"
    echo $dirname
done
exit
```

with this script, the output is always one order depth too little

output:

```
/storage/archive/mp3/A
/storage/archive/mp3/A
/storage/archive/mp3/A/3dir
/storage/archive/mp3/A/4dir/a4dir
```

but I want :

```
/storage/archive/mp3/A/1dir
/storage/archive/mp3/A/2dir
/storage/archive/mp3/A/3dir/a3dir
/storage/archive/mp3/A/4dir/a4dir/a44dir
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and *recursion*  `**`:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar

for dir in **/*/; do
    echo "$dir"
done
```